# Vim: Sourcecode output at startup

Tags: vim

Today I installed vim on my new computer and installed a couple of plugins. 
When I start vim (with no arguments and with files to edit) I get a lot of verbose output in my console which I never encountered before. 
This seems to be something from the vim sourcecode or from a plugin but I couldn't encounter where it comes from and especially why.

I'm interested in tracking down this issue. How can I do that?
I tried searching for some of these lines in my plugin folder but got no results and starting with the -D flag also gave me no hint. Google and SO search also yielded no results for me. 
Additionally I tried to disable each plugin seperately but this also failed.

Thanks.
PS: I would like to provide a picture but since the output is more than 150 lines long this is not a good idea since it doesn't seem to be related with a plugin and I don't have enough reputation.

Maybe a very small part of it:

```
syntaxset  FileType
*exe "set syntax=" . expand("<amatch>")
filetypedetect  StdinReadPost
...
svn-commit*.tmp
setf svn
Xresources*
call s:StarSetf('xdefaults')
*/app-defaults/*
```

Remark: This is not representative since it is randomly chosen from the terminal output, I just wanted to give an impression what is going on.

EDIT: This is NOT an error, its just printing out some kind of source code. Everything is working fine otherwise.

SOLUTION: Removing the `autocmd` line without any further text did the job. Thanks to FDinoff. Debugging with `finish` is really pleasant.

Comment: Create a picture. Or at least copy some of the error messages. (And maybe  part of your vimrc). Without the error message we can't answer this.

Comment: Debugging tips: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Comment: Show your vimrc. I believe you have a stray `autocmd` (With no other text after it) somewhere. The output appears to be the output when you type `:autocmd` on the command line (with some formatting striped). You should see a header `--- Auto-Commands ---` at the top if I'm right.

Comment: this was the bug! with `finish` commands in my vimrc I could track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Some Vim commands, when argument(s) are left off, print all existing such artifacts. This is useful during interactive use, but if you forget to specify the argument in your (plugin / `~/.vimrc`) configuration, this has the effect of "printing cryptic code" (an error would be more useful here).

Your output is likely from an `:autocmd` without arguments. Check your `~/.vimrc` and other files read during startup (see `:scriptnames`).